# Javascript - check array for value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple array with bank holidays:

```
var bank_holidays = ['06/04/2012','09/04/2012','07/05/2012','04/06/2012','05/06/2012','27/08/2012','25/12/2012','26/12/2012','01/01/2013','29/03/2013','01/04/2013','06/05/2013','27/05/2013'];
```

I want to do a simple check to see if certain dates exist as part of that array, I have tried:

```
if('06/04/2012' in bank_holidays) { alert('LOL'); }
if(bank_holidays['06/04/2012'] !== undefined) { alert 'LOL'; }
```

And a few other solutions with no joy, I have also tried replacing all of the forwarded slashes with a simple 'x' in case that was causing issues.

Any recommendations would be much appreciated, thank you!

(edit) Here's a **jsFiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/ENFWe/

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you don't care about legacy browsers:

```
if ( bank_holidays.indexOf( '06/04/2012' ) > -1 )
```

if you *do* care about legacy browsers, there is a shim available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Otherwise, jQuery provides an equivalent function:

```
if ( $.inArray( '06/04/2012', bank_holidays ) > -1 )
```

Comment: Should be the other way around: `arr.indexOf( value )`

Comment: Oops, I never remember that ;o)

Comment: @AlanKuras the jQuery version will. Or it will if you add the shim on MDN.

Comment: Exclusively developing for IE8 here unfortunately, and we are using jQuery - so will try the legacy browser option now! :)

Comment: Yep jquery is the solution, didnt saw that earlier

Comment: @Nick, you have my sympathy ...

Comment: Hm, no joy unfortunately... it still won't display the 'lol' - I wonder if the slashes are causing the problem? Will try replacing with xs

Comment: @Nick, it should work ... http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ycDkj/

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
// this will fix old browsers
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if (this[i] === value) {
        return i;
      }
    }

    return -1;
  }
}

// example
if ([1, 2, 3].indexOf(2) != -1) {
  // yay!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < bank_holidays.length; i++) {
    if (bank_holidays[i] === '06/04/2012') {
        alert('LOL');
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ENFWe/4/)

Comment: Checking the complete array is not efficient in terms of computational complexity

Comment: Absolute rubbish and a ridiculous micro optimisation suggestion - as the OP states it's a simple array and if there is a match the OP can always break thus not checking the complete array.