# javascript string in list returns false

Tags: javascript

My site just started returning false for the following javascript check.  I am trying to understand why.

```
_test = ["0e52a313167fecc07c9507fcf7257f79"]
"0e52a313167fecc07c9507fcf7257f79" in _test
>>> false
_test[0] === "0e52a313167fecc07c9507fcf7257f79"
>>> true
```

Can someone help me understand why ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - check array for value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015469/javascript-check-array-for-value)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the `in` operator tests if a property is in an object. For example

```
var test = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2 
};

"a" in test == true;
"c" in test == false;
```

You want to test if an array contains a specific object. You should use the Array#indexOf method.

```
test.indexOf("0e52...") != -1 // -1 means "not found", anything else simply indicates the index of the object in the array.
```

Array#indexOf at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 1):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) :

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the
>   specified object.

It checks the key, not the value.

There, the property key would be `0`, not `"0e52a313167fecc07c9507fcf7257f79"`.

You can test that `0 in _test` is `true`.

If you want to check if a value is in an array, use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) :

```
_test.indexOf("0e52a313167fecc07c9507fcf7257f79")!==-1
```

(a shim given by the MDN is necessary for IE8)

Answer (score 0):

"in" operator searches in object keys, not values. You will have to use indexOf and take care of its non implentation in previous IE versions. So you may find a cross browser implementation for the Array.prototype.indexOf method on the first google result.