# Checking if an array contains a value? (I've tried some techniques but I'm still a bit lost)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a beginner at JavaScript (beginner as in studying for about a week) and I'm stuck on how I can check if an array contains a certain string. [Here](http://codepen.io/kayesspea/pen/yavYXX?editors=1010) I've made a word-guessing game.

I declare the `function` 'contains' like this:

```
function contains(thing, array){
  if(thing in array){
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but the value is always false.

The function uses the third technique [here](http://www.endmemo.com/js/arrcontains.php). But I've also tried using the accepted technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015469/javascript-check-array-for-value), both with the same result.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: use the [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) method of arrays.

Comment: Please paste your code *(a minimal reproduction of the non-working part)* here so that we don't need to visit another site, and so that your question will make sense if that link ever dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to make a separate answer to make sure this is clear.  The correct approach to see if something is in an array:

```
var myArr = ['apples', 'bananas', 'pears'];

if (myArr.indexOf('pears') > -1) { // myArr.indexOf('pears') will equal the number 2
    console.log('we got pears'); // this will log
}

if (myArr.indexOf('hotdogs') > -1) { // since it's not in the array, it's -1
    console.log('hotdog!'); // this will not log
}
```

Finally please note that a `for...in` loop actually *should not be used to iterate over arrays* -- it really exists to iterate over keys in an object. For iterating over arrays in JS, a classic `for` loop is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) method.
The [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator checks for the existence of keys, not of values.
You, as well, can use a `for..in` loop, to iterate over all keys of an object:

```
for (key in object)
    console.log(object[key])
```

In the case of arrays, it would give the same result as

```
for (index=0; index<array.length; index++)
    console.log(array[i])
```

Comment: `for-in` is used for general property enumeration, which can include arrays, but generally is avoided for that purpose.  The `in` operator is used for checking existence of a property. I can't tell which you're referring to in your answer.

Comment: And two of the OP's links refer to `.indexOf()`, so more specific help is needed.

Comment: @Syntac-- correct on needing to use indexOf -- however, please note that a `for...in` loop actually should not be used to iterate over arrays -- it really exists to iterate over keys in an object.  For iterating over arrays in JS, a classic `for` loop is the correct approach.

Comment: `for-in` is not "the same as" `for`. There are important differences. However, the OP is actually doing `if(thing in array){`, which is about property checking, not iteration.